# Object foo has no method 'toLowercase'

Tags: javascript, string, object, tolower

I'm trying to get a lowercase value of each key in said object.

```
for (each in {'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}) {
    console.log(typeof each, each.toLowercase());
}
```

The error I get is `Object foo has no method 'toLowercase'`, yet `typeof each` returns `'string'`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) with a capital "C".

Comment: Oh wow! This is what I get for coding after a long day at work. Thanks